# Some reference items do not work, nor is there references at the end

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have been trying to fix this for hours in vain, I have no idea why this does not work.

I used `\bibliography{dci}`, 
`\bibliographystyle{acl_natbib}` at the end according to the instructions, and mostly `\citet{}`, `\citep{}`, and `\citealp` in context. Could anyone kindly help take a look? Much appreciated!

Here is the `MWE.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{acl2019}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{url}


\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}
\title{My Paper}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{Related Work}\label{sec:lit}
(e.g. \citealp{ekman1991invited}, \citealp{streeter1977pitch}) 
 \citep{pennebaker2001linguistic}
\citet{bachenko2008verification} 
\citet{ott2011finding} 
 \citet{hancock2007lying,mihalcea2009lie}

\bibliography{my_ref}
\bibliographystyle{acl_natbib}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Here is `my_ref.bib`:

```
@article{ekman1991invited,
  title={Invited article: Face, voice, and body in detecting deceit},
  author={Ekman, Paul and O'Sullivan, Maureen and Friesen, Wallace V and Scherer, Klaus R},
  journal={Journal of nonverbal behavior},
  volume={15},
  number={2},
  pages={125--135},
  year={1991},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{streeter1977pitch,
  title={Pitch changes during attempted deception.},
  author={Streeter, Lynn A and Krauss, Robert M and Geller, Valerie and Olson, Christopher and Apple, William},
  journal={Journal of personality and social psychology},
  volume={35},
  number={5},
  pages={345},
  year={1977},
  publisher={American Psychological Association}
}
@article{pennebaker1999linguistic,
  title={Linguistic styles: Language use as an individual difference.},
  author={Pennebaker, James W and King, Laura A},
  journal={Journal of personality and social psychology},
  volume={77},
  number={6},
  pages={1296},
  year={1999},
  publisher={American Psychological Association}
}
@inproceedings{ott2011finding,
  title={Finding deceptive opinion spam by any stretch of the imagination},
  author={Ott, Myle and Choi, Yejin and Cardie, Claire and Hancock, Jeffrey T},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 49th Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics: Human Language Technologies-Volume 1},
  pages={309--319},
  year={2011},
  organization={Association for Computational Linguistics}
}
@inproceedings{bachenko2008verification,
  title={Verification and implementation of language-based deception indicators in civil and criminal narratives},
  author={Bachenko, Joan and Fitzpatrick, Eileen and Schonwetter, Michael},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 22nd International Conference on Computational Linguistics-Volume 1},
  pages={41--48},
  year={2008},
  organization={Association for Computational Linguistics}
}
@article{hancock2007lying,
  title={On lying and being lied to: A linguistic analysis of deception in computer-mediated communication},
  author={Hancock, Jeffrey T and Curry, Lauren E and Goorha, Saurabh and Woodworth, Michael},
  journal={Discourse Processes},
  volume={45},
  number={1},
  pages={1--23},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
@inproceedings{mihalcea2009lie,
  title={The lie detector: Explorations in the automatic recognition of deceptive language},
  author={Mihalcea, Rada and Strapparava, Carlo},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the ACL-IJCNLP 2009 Conference Short Papers},
  pages={309--312},
  year={2009},
  organization={Association for Computational Linguistics}
}
```

Here is the `.blg` file:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: acl2019.aux
I couldn't open database file dci.bib
---line 26 of file acl2019.aux
 : \bibdata{dci
 :             }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
The style file: acl_natbib.bst
I found no database files---while reading file acl2019.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "ekman1991invited"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "streeter1977pitch"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "newman2003lying"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "pennebaker2001linguistic"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "bachenko2008verification"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "ott2011finding"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "hancock2007lying"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "mihalcea2009lie"
You've used 0 entries,
            2936 wiz_defined-function locations,
            599 strings with 4723 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 20 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 8
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 1
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 1
int.to.chr$ -- 1
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 4
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 1
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0 
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 3
(There were 2 error messages)
```

And here is the `.log` file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.5.24)  4 MAR 2019 09:43
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**acl2019
(./acl2019.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./acl2019.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen103
\Hy@linkcounter=\count87
\Hy@pagecounter=\count88

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count89

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count90

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5041.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen104
\Fld@menulength=\count91
\Field@Width=\dimen105
\Fld@charsize=\dimen106
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6295.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6300.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6303.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6310.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6315.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6320.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6325.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6365.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6369.
\Hy@abspage=\count92
\c@Item=\count93
\c@Hfootnote=\count94
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count95
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count96

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip43
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
\Gread@gobject=\count97
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 105.

Conference Style for ACL 2019
\titlebox=\skip44
\aclrulerbox=\box26
\aclrulercount=\count98
\aclruleroffset=\dimen107
\cv@lineheight=\dimen108
\cv@boxheight=\dimen109
\cv@tmpbox=\box27
\cv@refno=\count99
\cv@tot=\count100
\cv@tmpc@=\count101
\cv@tmpc=\count102
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Package: caption 2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 57.
\captionmargin=\dimen110
\captionmargin@=\dimen111
\captionwidth=\dimen112
\caption@tempdima=\dimen113
\caption@indent=\dimen114
\caption@parindent=\dimen115
\caption@hangindent=\dimen116
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count103
Package caption Info: hyperref package is loaded.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip45
\bibsep=\skip46
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count104
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/05/04 v2.2 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count105
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty
Package: times 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty
Package: latexsym 1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
\symlasy=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/lasy/m/n --> U/lasy/b/n on input line 52.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks15
\verbatim@line=\toks16
\verbatim@in@stream=\read1
)
(./acl2019.aux)
\openout1 = `acl2019.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 15.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box28
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 15.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count106
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 15.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 15.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 15.

(./acl2019.out) (./acl2019.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `acl2019.out'.


(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count107
\scratchdimen=\dimen117
\scratchbox=\box29
\nofMPsegments=\count108
\nofMParguments=\count109
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count110
\MPscratchDim=\dimen118
\MPnumerator=\count111
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count112
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <14.4> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+lasy on input line 16.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd
File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 20.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ekman1991invited' on page 1 undefined on inpu
t line 20.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `streeter1977pitch' on page 1 undefined on inp
ut line 20.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `newman2003lying' on page 1 undefined on input
 line 20.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pennebaker2001linguistic' on page 1 undefined
 on input line 22.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `bachenko2008verification' on page 1 undefined
 on input line 23.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ott2011finding' on page 1 undefined on input 
line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `hancock2007lying' on page 1 undefined on inpu
t line 26.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `mihalcea2009lie' on page 1 undefined on input
 line 26.

(./acl2019.bbl

./acl2019.bbl:4: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \end{thebibliography}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

)

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 37.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}




]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 37.

(./acl2019.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 37.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 37.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `acl2019.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 37.
 )
(\end occurred when \iffalse on line 351 was incomplete) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7051 strings out of 493089
 104952 string characters out of 6134842
 196824 words of memory out of 5000000
 10498 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 17348 words of font info for 43 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 43i,10n,40p,1006b,316s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/201
5/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvb8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/typ
e1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/tim
es/utmr8a.pfb>
Output written on ./acl2019.pdf (1 page, 31848 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 28 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 21 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 4 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Here is the folder:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uqj8xsxu291iqoj/AACHhF2DcylH1N-xHnXadEOGa?dl=0

Here is the style file `acl_natbib.bst`:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdou129ru0g4xdr/acl_natbib.bst?dl=0

Comment: Would it be possible to reduce the off-site resource to a small example document with only the most important packages and a few example citations that you can post as copyable text directly in the question (what is often called an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Comment: As always on this site we do not like going off site for data. Off site data also makes your question unusable for others later on as the data linked to is probably not available any more. SO please copy your data to your question instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I am adding to @moewe's commant, that many times, while minimizing your code to a MWE, the problem gets obvious and even if you don't find yourself the solution, you sure can make more clear the specific problem in your question and you will get a more accurate and a faster answer

Comment: @moewe,@daleif,@koleygr, thanks very much for your comments! I have edited as per your suggestions!

Comment: If I compile the file with the class and sty files from http://www.acl2019.org/EN/call-for-papers.xhtml I get an error (`patch failed`), but if I ignore the error I can compile the document. After the usual LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX route most citations and the bibliography show alright. `pennebaker2001linguistic` as well as `hancock2007lying` and `mihalcea2009lie` do not show up because they are missing in the `.bib` file. Apart from that things look OK. (The patching error is annoying, but you probably can't do more than complain to the editor of the conference..)

Comment: @moewe, thanks so much! Would you mind letting me the editor with which you compiled?

Comment: I used TeXworks, but the editor should not matter. What matters is the calls you make to compile (I used `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`) and to some extent the package versions installed on your system (I'm running a fully updated MikTeX system). Do you get any errors or warning when you run the exact MWE you posted?

Comment: Yes I get all the question marks instead of references

Comment: If you get question marks after running LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX you should also get more helpful warning or error messages. Post the complete `.blg` file and check the `.log` file for warnings and errors and post those as well.

Comment: @moewe, thanks! I have added .blg and .log to the question...

Comment: BibTeX can't find the `.bib` file: `I couldn't open database file dci.bib` Make sure that the file name is spelled correctly (case might matter, so check that it is not called `DCI.bib` or similar). Make sure that `dci.bib` is in the same folder as your main `.tex` file.